# Swift NSObject hash table

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dropbox

I'm trying to use hash tables in swift like in objective c:

I'm trying to create the code below in swift (from the [dropbox datastore api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/ios)):

```
NSArray *results = [tasksTbl query:@{ @"completed": @NO } error:nil];
```

The bit which is giving me trouble is the `query:@{ @"completed": @NO }`.

What is the equivalent of this in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work (sorry, untested):

`tasksTbl.query(["completed": false], error: nil)`